# Bibliography sorting order by Czech alphabet in Context

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, context, sorting

I am trying to sort bibliographical references for my thesis in ConTeXt, and I need to be able to set the sorting order by Czech alphabet (e.g., C,Č,D,....Ch,...etc.). English sorting puts Ch before C or Č, but in Czech it needs to be after D. Any ideas?

Here is the minimal example:

```
\mainlanguage[cz]

\usebtxdataset[bibliotest.bib]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\unprotect
\def\textampersand{a}
\protect


 \setupbtx
 [apa:cite]
 [left=,
  right=,
separator:2={\btxsemicolon}, % :0 and :1 - between items of a list
separator:3={\btxsemicolon},
separator:4={\btxsemicolon},
separator:names:2={\btxcomma},
separator:names:3={\btxcomma},
separator:names:4={\btxcomma},   
etaldisplay=3,
etallimit=3
]



\starttext

\cite[righttext={{123},{116-156}}][Danton2004, Cicikova2011].

\cite[Cicikova2011]

\cite[Chichikova1978]

\startchapter[title=Bibliografie]
\placelistofpublications
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

And here is the bibliotext.bib

```
@book{Danton2004,
address = {Oxford},
author = {Danton, Gocha R. and {De Angelis}, Franco},
publisher = {Oxford University School of Archaeology},
title = {{The archaeology of Greek colonisation: essays dedicated to Sir John Boardman}},
year = {2004}
 }

@article{Cicikova2011,
address = {Kazanlak},
annote = {PDF},
author = {{\v{C}}i{\v{c}}ikova, M},
pages = {116--121},
journal = {{Varia Thracica}},
title = {{Article Title}},
year = {2011}
}

@book{Chichikova1978,
address = {Oxford},
author = {Chichikova, Maria and Dimitrov, Dimitur P. and Alexieva, Marguerite and Author, Name},
isbn = {0-86054-003-0},
keywords = {Seuthopolis,Thracians},
language = {eng},
publisher = {BAR Supplementary Series 38},
title = {{The Thracian city of Seuthopolis}},
year = {1978}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in ConTeXt (the APA definitions are broken, APS for example works just fine), you should ask the [ConTeXt-Mailinglist](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) for help.

In the mean time you can try the following workaround:

1. Do sort the entries in your .bib-file manually
2. Use `sorttype=index` to let the bibliography use the sort order of the .bib-file:

   ```
   \definebtxrendering
   [apa] 
   [specification=apa,
    sorttype=index]
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, even though I would prefer not to do that manually as my thesis .bib file has few hundred references. I have asked the mailing list, will see.

Comment: You can use a tool like JabRef or BibDesk to do the sorting for you. A word of warning: The new publication system for ConTeXt, which you are using, is still in development and **not** ready for production. I wouldn't recommend it for something as critical as a thesis...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the  support from Alan Blaslau and Hans Hagen from the ConTeXt malining list, the problem has been solved by adding the following code anywhere into the document:

```
\startluacode
    sorters.setlanguage("cz")
\stopluacode
```